# My insert data is is created but the fields are empty - mySQL. WHY?

Tags: mysql

I have an HTML form that inserts a record into my table / database.  I get a successful echo and a new row appears in the table, but the fields are empty in the database.

What could I be doing wrong?

Here is my php code:

```
 <?
$host="localhost"; 
$username="XXXXXX";
$password="XXXXXX";
$db_name="XXXXXX"; 
$tbl_name="cartons_current";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $order = "INSERT INTO cartons_current
(part_no, description, count, size, min, max, qty)
VALUES
('$part_no', '$description', '$count', '$size', '$min', '$max', '$qty')";

    $result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
    if($result){
echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
    } else{
echo("<br>Input data is fail");
    }
```

?>

Comment: Do you have something in the variables you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables `$part_no`, `$description` doesn't appear magiacally (due to turned off `register_globals`)

So you need to use `$_GET` or `$_POST` arrays to retrieve the data (`$_GET['part_no']`, etc)

PS: google something about sql injections